# Infinite calculations in finite time

Tags: computability, computation-models

This is probably a silly thought, but suppose we have a computer that's programmed to perform an infinite sequence of calculations and suppose the $i^\text{th}$ calculation takes $1/2^i$ seconds to complete.  Then this computer can do an infinite number of calculations in a finite amount of time.

Why is this impossible?  Is there a lower bound on how long it takes to carry out a non-trivial calculation?

Comment: Related concept, infinite computations using finite energy: [Dyson's eternal intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson's_eternal_intelligence).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This "kind" of computer is known as a [Zeno Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_machine). Its computational model falls into a category called [Hypercomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation). Hypercomputational models are mathematical abstractions, and because of the ways in which they are defined to work, they aren't physically possible.

Take your Zeno Machine for example. If we imagine the Zeno Machine to be a calculating machine of any kind, whether it uses an abacus or integrated circuit doesn't matter. Say the program data used by the machine is fed to it by an infinitely long tape of symbols (just like a Turing Machine).

Of course, we know from mathematics that:

$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}... = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^n $

which we say is equal to $1$. Thus the computation should complete in 1 second because the sum absolutely converges.

But this convergence is, of course,  dependent on $n$ going to (and reaching) infinity. In the physical sense, this means that as the time required for each calculation gets smaller, the "read head" of the calculating machine will have to zip along the symbols in the tape faster and faster. At some point, this speed will exceed the speed of light.

So answering your second question, the absolute lowest-possible bound on a calculation would probably be on the order of the Planck time, given the speed of light as the primary limiting factor in theoretical, but physically-plausible models of computation.

Comment: There is also the energy requirements for each operation, [flipping a bit $2^{256}$  times requires several orders of magnitude more energy than is in our sun](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/25392/5220)

Comment: Does this program: _10:GOTO 10_ finish on the Zeno Machine?

Comment: In simpler terms, the math presupposes that a "calculation" is infinitely divisible in scope.  However that's not the case with any physical machine, as you eventually reach a point where you've hit the smallest unit of work that the machine can perform.  It's not possible to continue subdividing the calculation after that point, even though the math allows you to.  In other words, the machine craps out long before you actually approach the end of the infinite series of calculations.  At some point the time per calculation stops decreasing, and you end up needing infinite time.

Comment: @Cano64 I don't think so. I believe the criterion for decidability in hypercomputation is that the time-sum of the calculation absolutely converges.

Answer (score 6):

The time taken for a primitive computation is limited by the speed of light and the size of atoms, as far as we understand physics on this very day, 15 September, 2015.

The computation unit needs to be built out of something of non-zero size (atoms) and for the computation to work, electricity or light will need to zip across it, which will be limited by how long it takes light to zip across the non-zero distance.

Comment: One concrete example in recent history of science pushing boundaries is [giant magnetoresistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_magnetoresistance), a Nobel-prize-winning discovery that allowed for data density on hard drives previously thought impossible. There are many, many more if you go back; try to explain the possibility of a "smartphone" to a person from 1500 AD. (They may just burn you as a witch, so be careful.) So I think we should not assume that our current knowledge of physics induces hard bounds on what is possible.

Answer (score -1):

"Theory of Everything"'s answer is good, but I want to add some intuition as to why $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^n$ converges to $1$, which we can translate into an answer to this question:

Imagine that you have a red and a blue bucket; the blue bucket contains one liter of water and the red bucket is empty. You pour half of the water from the blue into the red. Now both buckets have $\frac{1}{2}$ liter of water in them. You again pour half of what is in the blue bucket into the red, there is now $\frac{1}{4}$ liter of water in the blue bucket and $\frac{3}{4}$ liter in the red. Now you continue, always pouring half of what is in the blue bucket into the red bucket. Clearly you will never get more than one liter into the red bucket, and just as clearly you will always have more water in the blue bucket to pour over.

To complete the analogy; the blue bucket contains time, exactly twice as much time as the first computation $c_1$ takes. For each step of the computation you use up half of the remaining computation-time and pour it into the red bucket of used time. Just as the red bucket of water can't contain more water than the blue contained, the red bucket of used time can not contain more than twice the computation time of $c_1$. And just as there were always water left in the blue bucket we will always have a tiny bit of computation-time left for the next computation.

**Edit**: As noted by @aroth, this analogy assumes that we can keep dividing water forever; that there is no smallest indivisible atom. Which raises the interesting (I think) point that we must also assume time to be arbitrarily divisible for the computation to finish in finite time.

Comment: "and just as clearly you will always have more water in the blue bucket to pour over" - Not necessarily.  With a precise-enough pouring apparatus you'll eventually reach a point where there are 2 molecules of water in the blue bucket.  Then 1 molecule.  Then you either pour the last molecule, or you don't.  Or you break it down into its base atoms, but then it's no longer water (or pourable at STP).  Point is, you'll get down to the last molecule of water _well before_ you get to the end of the infinite series, so there won't "always" be water in the blue bucket.

Comment: @aroth: yeah true, for the analogy to work you must think about water as satisfying "density", a kind of "always divisibility". Your point is interesting as it highlights something important; for the computation to finish in finite time, time also needs to be dense/always divisible. If there exists a shortest amount of time, a non-divisible atomic unit of time, then the infinite computation will take infinite time (or each computation must take no time each after some point).

Comment: @epa095 If you take water to be infinitely subdivisible, you're no longer providing intuition. You're just restating the problem ("Computer $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}$") in a different way, i.e., by calling the quantity $2^{-i}$ an "amount of water" instead of a "rational number".

Comment: @david-richerby: Isn't restating the problem in a different way, giving an easier way to think about it, **exactly** what it is to provide intuition? Also note that you are **also** restating the problem, from amount of time to the sum of rational numbers. An (extremely) short step yes, but a restating none the less. If you know about convergence of sums of rational numbers, that restating makes it easier to understand, but for some I am certain that it is easier to understand it in terms of water. It is at least how I first understood why some infinite sums converged and some not.

Comment: @epa095 Providing intuition involves explaining an unfamiliar situation by reference to a familiar situation and using the familiarity with one situation to help understanding of the other. You're not doing that: you're trying to explain one unfamiliar situation (computing an infinite, convergent sum) by another (pouring buckets of infinitely divisible water with perfect accuracy). People who know about convergence of sums don't need the analogy; for people who don't know about convergence of sums, renaming "rational number" to "quantity of hypothetical water" doesn't help.

Comment: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3892 - Sorry, couldn't resist!